# create class to hold array of values

Tags: javascript

I want to create a class that contains methods where I provide a name like Tom the method should return Tom1, Tom2 etc similarly for John it should return John1, John2 etc

What is the correct syntax for it?

```
class Name {
    let names = {};
    Name() {
        
    }
    assign(name) {
        var count = names[name];
        if(!count) {
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;
        names[name] = count;
        return name +""+count;
    }
    
    remove(name) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `names` is not an array. How do you use `Name`? May you share that code as well?

Comment: Your code example doesn't run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` is not allowed at that second line. It seems your intention was to make `names` an instance property. So then you should also reference it as `this.names` further down your code. This `this.` prefix is required in JavaScript (unlike in Java)

Also, I get the impression you think `Name` is the name of the explicit constructor function (like in Java), but that isn't the case. In a JavaScript `class` block you provide constructor code in a function called `constructor` -- a class does not need to have one if you have nothing for it do to:

```js
class Name {
    names = {};  // public instance property

    assign(name) {
        var count = this.names[name];  // must use this to reference it
        if(!count) {
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;
        this.names[name] = count;
        return name +""+count;
    }
    
    remove(name) {
        delete this.names[name];
    }
}

let name = new Name();
console.log(name.assign("John"));
console.log(name.assign("Helen"));
console.log(name.assign("John"));
console.log(name.assign("Helen"));
name.remove("John");
console.log(name.assign("John"));
```

We could question whether a class is really the right tool for this, as it seems unlikely you would create another instance of `Name`. Use an object instead.

```js
let Name = {
    names: {},

    assign(name) {
        var count = this.names[name];
        if(!count) {
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;
        this.names[name] = count;
        return name +""+count;
    },
    
    remove(name) {
        delete this.names[name];
    }
};

console.log(Name.assign("John"));
console.log(Name.assign("Helen"));
console.log(Name.assign("John"));
console.log(Name.assign("Helen"));
Name.remove("John");
console.log(Name.assign("John"));
```

Comment: It's still conventional to use an initial capital for the object form, e.g. `Math.xxx`.